# Fixed position sidebar with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I incorporate the following sidebar menu feature using jQuery where the menu on the left re-appears as the user scrolls down the page?

Here's an [example sidebar menu](http://www.internode.on.net/residential/broadband/adsl/all_plans/).

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good tutorial over at Nettuts about this exact thing:

[Creating a Floating HTML Menu Using jQuery and CSS](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/creating-a-floating-html-menu-using-jquery-and-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery CSS Control:

http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

and tutorial is also nice,

if you are using bootstrap then you can use affix control of bootstrap, that is also good